# Can those codes be simplified?

Tags: javascript

I have written this program, but I am not sure whether it can be simplified. Thanks,

Code:

```js
function detect(a, b, c) {
    if (a.length === 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a.length > 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.length === 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length === 0) {
        return 2;
    } else if (a.length === 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length > 0) {
        return 3;
    } else if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length === 0) {
        return 4;
    } else if (a.length === 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length > 0) {
        return 5;
    } else if (a.length > 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length > 0) {
        return 6;
    } else if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length > 0) {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can get rid of every `else` for a start - but there is an easier way

Comment: Getting rid of else statements will likely lead to useless checks. For example, say the first condition evaluates to true, there is no need to check the rest, so keeping `else` is better.

Comment: @IrfanullahJan each `if` has return, so there will be no useless checks

Comment: This question is probably off topic for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Drop the `else`s:

```
function detect(a, b, c) {
    if (a.length === 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length === 0) return 0;
    if (a.length > 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length === 0) return 1;
    if (a.length === 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length === 0) return 2;
    if (a.length === 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length > 0) return 3;
    if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length === 0) return 4;
    if (a.length === 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length > 0) return 5;
    if (a.length > 0 && b.length === 0 && c.length > 0) return 6;
    if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0 && c.length > 0) return 7;
}
```

Use variables for shared expressions:

```
function detect(a, b, c) {
    const aEmpty = a.length === 0;
    const bEmpty = b.length === 0;
    const cEmpty = c.length === 0;
    if ( aEmpty &&  bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 0;
    if (!aEmpty &&  bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 1;
    if ( aEmpty && !bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 2;
    if ( aEmpty &&  bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 3;
    if (!aEmpty && !bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 4;
    if ( aEmpty && !bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 5;
    if (!aEmpty &&  bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 6;
    if (!aEmpty && !bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 7;
}
```

Reorder to form a binary counter pattern:

```
function detect(a, b, c) {
    const aEmpty = a.length === 0;
    const bEmpty = b.length === 0;
    const cEmpty = c.length === 0;
    if (!aEmpty && !bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 7;
    if (!aEmpty && !bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 4;
    if (!aEmpty &&  bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 6;
    if (!aEmpty &&  bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 1;
    if ( aEmpty && !bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 5;
    if ( aEmpty && !bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 2;
    if ( aEmpty &&  bEmpty && !cEmpty) return 3;
    if ( aEmpty &&  bEmpty &&  cEmpty) return 0;
}
```

Create the index using a bit operation formula:

```
function detect(a, b, c) {
    const aEmpty = a.length === 0;
    const bEmpty = b.length === 0;
    const cEmpty = c.length === 0;
    const index = aEmpty << 2 | bEmpty << 1 | cEmpty << 0;
    if (index === 0) return 7;
    if (index === 1) return 4;
    if (index === 2) return 6;
    if (index === 3) return 1;
    if (index === 4) return 5;
    if (index === 5) return 2;
    if (index === 6) return 3;
    if (index === 7) return 0;
}
```

Just index into an array:

```
function detect(a, b, c) {
    const aEmpty = a.length === 0;
    const bEmpty = b.length === 0;
    const cEmpty = c.length === 0;
    const index = aEmpty << 2 | bEmpty << 1 | cEmpty << 0;
    const array = [7, 4, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0];
    return array[index]
}
```

Optionally, get rid of the temporary variables:

```
const detect = (a, b, c) => [7, 4, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0][(a.length === 0) << 2 | (b.length === 0) << 1 | (c.length === 0) << 0];
```

[Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) further to just

```
const detect=(a,b,c)=>[0,3,2,5,1,6,4,7][!a.length<<2|!b.length<<1|!c.length]
```

Choose whichever level of conciseness you are comfortable with. I would however recommend a version that clearly (either through code or formatting) points out the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest version I can come up with:

```js
function detect(a, b, c) {
    return [0,1,2,4,3,6,5,7][(a.length>0)|((b.length>0)<<1)|((c.length>0)<<2)];
}

// test methods:
console.log(detect([], [], []) + ' ' + detect([1], [], []));
console.log(detect([], [1], []) + ' ' + detect([], [], [1]));
console.log(detect([1], [1], []) + ' ' + detect([], [1], [1]));
console.log(detect([1], [], [1]) + ' ' + detect([1], [1], [1]));
```

Comment: You're too quick :p

Comment: Shortest yes, simplest maybe not :-) But I arrived at basically the same solution

Comment: @Bergi I like your variant with `!a.length` more :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function detect(a, b, c) {
    result=0;
    if (a.length > 0){
        result=result+1;
    }
    if (b.length > 0){
        result=result+2;
    }
    if (c.length > 0){
        result=result+4;
    }
    returnList=[0,1,2,4,3,6,5,7];
    return returnList[result];
}
```

This function should work as same.

Although I feel this is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach these types of problems is to hardcode condition -> result maps.

```js
function detect(a, b, c) {
  const aIndex = a.length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
  const bIndex = b.length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
  const cIndex = c.length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
  const conditionMap = [
    [
      [0, 3],
      [2, 5],
    ],
    [
      [1, 6],
      [4, 7],
    ]
  ]
  console.log(`(${a.length}, ${b.length}, ${c.length}):`, conditionMap[aIndex][bIndex][cIndex]);
  return conditionMap[aIndex][bIndex][cIndex];
}

console.log("For (a, b, c) lengths:");
detect([], [], []);
detect([1], [], []);
detect([], [1, 1], []);
detect([], [], [1]);
detect([1], [1], []);
detect([], [1], [1]);
detect([1], [], [1]);
detect([1], [1], [1, 0]);
```